# azure api manager recreate deleted unlimited product

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

currently, by mistake, I deleted our unlimited product from azure API manager. do we have any way to recover back this product back.

P.S. we are no way can use Azure git repository as we mirror it from other repo.

Comment: Was there anything special about this product, like custom policies? Does it have many users? Do you control subscription keys?

Comment: by default when we create Azure API manager it is creating two products starter and unlimited product. as per azure documentation unlimited product is the best option for production with better control on rate limit

Answer (score 0):

If you were relying on "Unlimnited" product created by default with APIM service, then it's nothing special, really. Just open "Products" screen and create a new product, can even call it "Unlimited" again. Products themselves are nothing special, you can create as many as you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-add-products.

The only thing to keep in mind that every product has it's own subscriptions. If you delete product, it's subscriptions along with subscription keys are gone. So when you recreate product you'll have to resubscribe all users to this new product, and then distribute new subscriptions keys. Alternatively, if you have access to subscription keys that were used before, you can create new subscriptions with same keys via API or SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to recover the deleted products, unleash you have backup process (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore) or Azure git repository.If you don't have any other product or APIs configured on APIM, then delete the APIM and create again. If not, please follow the standard way to maintain APIs on APIM, (I can recommend this)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-add-products
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies